# Is there an RDF ontology for blogs?

Tags: rdf, blogs, semantic-web, rdfa

I'm setting up a blog, and I'm fascinated by RDF and the idea of the sematic web. I'd like to use RDFa to embed sematic data into my blog. There are several well know semantic web ontologies like FOAF for decribing people, ical for events, geo for places.

Is there an ontology for blogs? Something to say "This site is a blog. Foo is a blog entry. Foo was posted on (date here in ical or whatever), foo has X comments. Y is a comment on Foo. Y was left at (this time), Y was left by (someone)"?

**Update**:
I know about Dublin Core, that seems to cover a lot of stuff I want (e.g. "This was written at this time", "This was written by this person", "The title of this is whatever"). So that's goes about 75% of the way there. Is there anything that fully marks up blogs? Takes it to the next level? "This is a blog", "This is a comment on this entry", "This is the URL for a trackback on this blog", etc? If not I'll just make my own.

Comment: RSS 1.0 was an RDF based specification.  It covers most of what a blog is I believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[the SIOC ontology](http://rdfs.org/sioc/spec/) might be what you are looking for. its purpose is to express information about blogs, forums, wikis and other kinds of social media sites.

useful information:

- [a list of SIOC applications](http://rdfs.org/sioc/applications/)
- [SIOC plugin for WordPress](http://sioc-project.org/wordpress/)
- [Semantic Radar extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3886)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at SIOC (Semantically-Interlinked Online Communities) http://sioc-project.org/ 
I think it's exactly what you want.

To quote them:

> The SIOC (Semantically-Interlinked Online Communities) Core Ontology provides the main concepts and properties required to describe information from online communities (e.g., message boards, wikis, weblogs, etc.) on the Semantic Web.

If you need more, there are others depending on your needs (for tag or else) most of the time extending FOAF/SIOC/...

Answer (score 3):

Well one of the beauties of RDF schemas is the ability to extend them, and mix-and-match elements from eachother. So you could create your own, and use existing bits.

So I would go with a combination of [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/2008/01/14/dcterms.rdf#), for documents, publishing, etc, with [Friend Of A Friend](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/20071002.rdf) for people and social aspects to the blog. These are two of the most commonly used ontologies for general purposes.

Answer (score 1):

[Schema.org](http://schema.org) has published an [ontology for blog & blog posts](http://schema.org/BlogPosting).

Answer (score 0):

I did some research involving a fair number of RSS feeds a few months ago, and the most common schema we encountered (interleaved in the RSS tags) was [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/2008/01/14/dcterms.rdf#), which Ali A mentioned.

We were most interested in the [Well-Formed Web](http://wellformedweb.org/) tags for comment RSS feeds, but the Dublin Core stuff is probably what you're looking for. It's currently the most widespread RDF schema for blogs.

Answer (score 0):

[Less Talk, More Code](http://oxfordrepo.blogspot.com/) (by Ben O'Steen) has a post [Ditching the DB-based blog for a semantic one](http://oxfordrepo.blogspot.com/2008/04/ditching-db-based-blog-for-semantic-one.html)  that covers a lot of what is needed - it's worth a look.